# Format text in UITextField with new string for right alignment and currency?

Tags: swift

I've been working on this for three days. I'm trying to format the text in a UITextField to output in currency format and left aligned.  I can format the text in the variable to output as currency, but not in the textView, and NSTextAlignment keeps giving me an error.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class dollarFieldDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
var currentString = ""
var newCurrency = ""
var newText: NSString = ""

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    newText = textField.text
    textField.NSRightTextAlignment//Tried this several different ways, keep getting 'UITextField does not have member NSRightTextAlignment
    let convertToANumber = string.toInt() //check the replacment string for a Int.
    UIText
    // If string does not contain an Int, stringByReplacingCharactersInRange is not executed
    if convertToANumber != nil {

        currentString += string
        formatCurrency(string: currentString)
        newText = newText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: newCurrency)
        println("in newText")
        println(newText)
        return true
    }
    else {
       return false}//returns false if checkToSeeIfItsANumber is nil
}
func formatCurrency(#string: String) ->NSString{
    //println("format \(string)")
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    //formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
    formatter.currencySymbol = "$"
    var numberFromField = (NSString(string: currentString).doubleValue)/100
    newText = formatter.stringFromNumber(numberFromField)!
    //println(newCurrency)
    return newCurrency
}
```

}

Also the output in the textField is 1234, but the output in the debugger is $1234.56

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. And by that, I downloaded the solution.  However, I don't understand why it works.  Why does returning false (after converting the textField) give the correct solution?

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    newText = textField.text
    let convertToANumber = string.toInt() //check the replacment string for a Int.
    // If string does not contain an Int, stringByReplacingCharactersInRange is not executed
    if convertToANumber != nil {
        currentString += string
        formatCurrency(string: currentString)
        newText = newText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: newCurrency)

        textField.text = newText as String
        return false//sends correctly formatted $123.45 to viewController
    }
    else {
       return false}//returns false if checkToSeeIfItsANumber is nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line in your `viewDidLoad`, does it solve anything?

`textField.delegate = self`

Comment: No, this textFieldDelegate is in a separate file, so not in the original viewController.

Comment: I think it is something I just don't understand in the documentation.  I'm trying to get it to format as $0.00 to start, as I type, it would fill in $0.01, $0.12, $1.23, etc.  Yet  the `newText = newText.stringByReplacing..` is converting `newText` one character at a time. I tried overcoming this by creating the `newCurrency` variable, which is retaining the string I want, but not returning it to the textField, nor can I figure out how to implement the TextAlignment property from the documentation.